# How do I work around to close this modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog

So, I've been trying to play with the js on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/obvKxm) so that when you click the background, it closes the modal... But, I have two problems:

1. .modal is contained within .modal-background
2. I'm such a shameful noob that I can't seem to find a workaround.

Could you guys help? Anything so I can learn and fix :)

Here below is the js code:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass(buttonId);
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('#modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
  $('body').removeClass('modal-active');
});
```

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about how to prevent the modal to close on a direct click on it, but keeping a click on the background to close it (Like if you want to insert a button or anything into it)...

This will do:

```
$(".modal").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) but now, I can't close it at all, or am I missing something? I tried adding `<button type="button" id="close-btn">Close</button>` inside _.modal_ and the following code to close it

`$("#close-btn").click(function(){
 $("#modal-container").addClass("out");
 $("body").removeClass("modal-active");
});`

But nothing budges :(

Comment: The code to close the modal already exists... Try this simplier code for your button: `$("#close-btn").click(function(){ $("#modal-container").click(); });`. It will "simulate a click on the background".

Comment: Ok... There's an issue... Hold on.

Comment: Commenting the SVG out, in the HTML, resolves the issue without any visible effect on the expected result... I just don't know why it's there. See in the [**updated CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BQaPOZ?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you! You're a legend!